# How can I deploy a Vite-based React application on my local machine using an Apache Tomcat server?

Tags: reactjs, vite, tomcat9

I have tried to deploy like normal React app but it doesn't work for me? Is there anything need to be changed because of **Vite**?

Opened the `package.json` file in the project root, and added the below entry in the file and saved.

```json
{
    "homepage" : "``http://localhost:8089/``applicatin_name"
}
```

After that I have copied and pasted "`dist`" folder into the webapp folder in **TomcatServer** folder.

Comment: You probably need to set base in vite config file. IIRC Vite doesn’t care about the homepage field in package.json.

Comment: "but it doesn't work".  Are we supposed to guess?  Do you feel debugging details aren't important to get help?